# What is the code to handle file uploads in Python3 in a nice way to replace cgi.py when it deprecates in 3.13

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

I am trying to replace the cgi.py module code because it will be deprecated in Python 3.13. The code handles get and post methods, however, I'd like it to also be able to handle file uploads, what code would do this?

**Update**: I have answered my own question that works with Apache2 mod_cgi and provided the code utilizing multipart.

First, install the pip package multipart from https://github.com/defnull/multipart

```
pip install multipart
```

Next, here is my current code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# The MIT License
# Copyright 2023 BestInternetSearch.com Inc.
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the “Software”), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

import os
import sys
from html import escape
import urllib
from multipart import MultipartParser, MultiDict, parse_options_header

forms, files = MultiDict(), MultiDict()

class MyCGI():
    
    _os_environ = []
    _escape = True
    _data = {}
    
    def __init__(self, os_environ, escape=True):
        self._os_environ = os_environ
        self._escape = escape
        
def FieldStorage(self):
    e = self._os_environ
    if 'REQUEST_METHOD' in e:
        if e['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET':
            self._data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(e['QUERY_STRING'])
        elif e['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
            if 'CONTENT_TYPE' in e:
                content_type, options = parse_options_header(e['CONTENT_TYPE'])
                if 'multipart/form-data' in e['CONTENT_TYPE']:
                    if 'boundary' in e['CONTENT_TYPE']:
                        boundary = options.get("boundary", "")
                        if 'CONTENT_LENGTH' in e:
                            content_length = int(os.environ.get("CONTENT_LENGTH", "-1"))
                            stream = sys.stdin.buffer
                            for part in MultipartParser(stream, boundary, content_length):
                                if part.filename or not part.is_buffered():
                                    files[part.name] = part
                if 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in e['CONTENT_TYPE']:
                    self._data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(str(sys.stdin.read()), keep_blank_values=True)

    def getvalue(self, arg_key, default=''):
        if arg_key in self._data:
            value = self._data[arg_key]
            if isinstance(value, list):
                if self._escape == True:
                    return escape(self._data[arg_key][0])
                else:
                    self._data[arg_key][0]
            else:
                if self._escape == True:
                    return escape(value)
                else:
                    return value
        else:
            return default
```

Usage:

```
mycgi = MyCGI(os.environ)
mycgi.FieldStorage()
user = mycgi.getvalue('user')      

And uploading files something like:
curl -F "text=default" -F "filename=@/home/computer/Desktop/aa.png" -F "filename=@/home/computer/Desktop/bb.png" http://example_website.com

filenames = files.getall('filename')
for x, file in enumerate(filenames):
    file.save_as(f"""/home/computer/Desktop/file{x}.png""")
```

Comment: Would this be what you need?
https://github.com/filestack/filestack-python

Comment: Nice for answering, though I'm looking more for the receiver of a file upload to process the upload, not to do the uploading, though TY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files that are uploaded by an http-browser are POSTed as multipart-form-data. There are several libraries that support parsing this data, e.g.:

- [multipart](https://github.com/defnull/multipart)
- [streaming-form-data](https://streaming-form-data.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [requests-toolbelt](https://pypi.org/project/requests-toolbelt/)'s MultipartDecoder
- [python-multipart](https://pypi.org/project/python-multipart/)

However you should consider to refactor your application, remove CGI and use one of the common and supported web frameworks.

**Update:** Here is a very basic cgi-script that uses the python-multipart package to extract information about fields and files from multipart form data:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys
import multipart as mp


print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
print("<!doctype html>\n")

# callbacks
def on_field(field):
    print(f"Parsed field: {field.field_name} with value {field.value}<br>")

def on_file(file):
    print(f"Parsed file: {file.field_name} with file name {file.file_name} and size {file.size}<br>")

# get header info
headers = {'Content-Type': os.environ['CONTENT_TYPE']}

if 'HTTP_X_FILE_NAME' in os.environ:
    headers['X-File-Name'] = os.environ['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']

if 'CONTENT_LENGTH' in os.environ:
    headers['Content-Length'] = os.environ['CONTENT_LENGTH']

# parse the form
mp.parse_form(headers, sys.stdin.buffer, on_field, on_file)

print("Done\n")
```

Comment: I took initiative and coded the start of the implementation using multipart at pythoncgi.net